# How to add multiple topics in JDBC Sink Connector configuration and get topics data in multiple target tables?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mssql-jdbc

Below is my JDBC-Sink connector configuration:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
behavior.on.null.values=ignore
table.name.format=kafka_Address_V1, kafka_Attribute_V1
connection.password=***********
topics=Address,Attribute
task.max=3
batch.size=500
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
auto.evolve=true
connection.user=user
name=sink-jdbc-connector
errors.tolerance=all
auto.create=true
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:DB;
insert.mode=upsert
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields=id
```

If I use this configuration I am getting single table in target database in this kafka_Address_V1, kafka_Attribute_V1 format, which is combination of these two.

[image]

Please let me know how can I use to store different topics data in different Tables by using JDBC-Sink Connector.

Comment: `topics` alone should create two tables. I didn't think tables can have commas. Why do you need `table.name.format`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have tried that way by removing table.name.format but table is not creating in target database. If I insert or update any record in source topic sink connector read that record but it didn't sent that record to target DB and in this case table is not created in target DB. Please let me know how can I proceed further so that I can achieve expected behavior of JDBC sink connector in this case.

Comment: Are you getting errors from connect when things don't send? I see you have `auto.create=true`, so the tables should automatically created based on the topic name itself, and so you don't really need `table.name.format` other than to match the expected table names.

Comment: yes, I got error, my topic name is like iq.db.topicName thats why it ius looking for iq db which is source DB, I have used  transform, dropPrefix to achive topicName. And I have used kafka_${topic}, it is creating table in target db for all the topics that I have defined in topics property. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping), `table.name.format` takes a single value, and defaults to using the topic name itself.

*Edit: courtesy of @OneCricketeer, you can also just use  `table.name.format=kafka_${topic}_V1`. The SMT below is useful for more complex transformations of the name.*

To achieve what you want you can use the [`RegExRouter` Single Message Transform](https://rmoff.net/2020/12/11/twelve-days-of-smt-day-4-regexrouter/) to modify the topic as its processed by Kafka Connect

Try this:

```json
transforms                             =changeTopicName
transforms.changeTopicName.type        =org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.changeTopicName.regex       =(.*)
transforms.changeTopicName.replacement =kafka_$1_V1
```

Comment: ‍♂️ yes it would. Good catch.